# How to visualize the working of CNN architecture here? I want to see how the images are processed at every layer along with ground truth

Tags: pytorch

I have two multi-focus images with their corresponding ground-truth images (in binary form) and I also have model saved in the directory after training. Now what I want is to see the working of each and every layer that how both images are processed inside its CNN architecture i.e i want to see feature maps at every layer. The two input images are of size 128 by 128 by 3. But CNN is taking both image combinedly 128 by 128 by 6.

I have tried the following code but still there are so many errors.
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 6, 9, 9], expected input[1, 2, 128, 128] to have 6 channels, but got 2 channels instead

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from net import Generator

model_path = "model/40_net_params.pkl"
model_state_dict = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')
model = Generator(n_residual_blocks=12)
model.load_state_dict(model_state_dict)

def get_layer_output(model, layer_name, input_image):
    # Extract the desired layer
    layer = getattr(model, layer_name)
    # Set the model to evaluation mode
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_image)
        layer_output = layer(output)
    return layer_output

input_image = torch.randn(1, 6, 128, 128)  # Assuming two multi-focus images as input with 6 channels

#layer_names = ["conv1", "conv2", "conv3", "conv4", "residual_blocks", "conv5", "conv6", "conv7", "conv8", "upsampling"]
layer_names = ["conv1", "conv2"]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(layer_names), ncols=1, figsize=(6, 2*len(layer_names)))

for i, layer_name in enumerate(layer_names):
    layer_output = get_layer_output(model, layer_name, input_image)
    layer_output_np = layer_output.detach().numpy()[0]
    layer_output_np = np.transpose(layer_output_np, (1, 2, 0))
    axs[i].imshow(layer_output_np)
    axs[i].set_title(layer_name)
    axs[i].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Please help. I am not able to generate features maps of every layer.

If possible please make me understand how both images along with ground truth is processed.

Thank you so much